# Let $f$ be holomorphic on connected open set $D$. Prove $u^4+v^4$ being constant implies $f=u+iv$ being constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

Differentiating $u^4+v^4$, we have
$$ 4u^3u_x + 4v^3v_x = 0 $$
$$ 4u^3u_y + 4v^3v_y = 0 $$

Then we have $$u^3v^3 u_x v_y = u^3v^3 u_y v_x.$$
If $uv\neq 0$, then we can apply Cauchy-Riemann condition to conclude $u,v$ are constant. However, what if $uv=0$? I struggle to proceed with this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply Cauchy-Riemann equation to the two equations you have got, we have
$$4u^3u_x-4v^3u_y=0$$
$$4v^3u_x+4u^3u_y=0$$
which is an linear equation of $u_x,u_y$ with the determinant of coefficient matrix $16(u^6+v^6)$.

Therefore, if the determinant is $0$ at some point in $D$, then $u^4+v^4\equiv 0$, which implies $f\equiv 0$, if the determinant is not $0$ at every point in $D$, then the equation has unique solution $u_x=u_y=0$, which implies $f$ is constant.

Comment: @MartinR Suppose $u(a,b)^6+v(a,b)^6=0$ for some point $(a,b)\in D$. Then we have $u(a,b)=0=v(a,b)$. Since $u^4+v^4$ is constant, we have $u^4+v^4=u(a,b)^4+v(a,b)^4=0$ on the whole $D$, so $u=v=0$ on whole $D$.

Comment: @durianice: Yes, you are right – my fault!

Answer (score 2):

If $uv=0$ it means that at least one of them is identically constant (being $D$ connected). Say $v\equiv0$. Then use CR equations to get that $u$ is constant. So $f$ is.

Comment: I don't get why $v$ would be identically zero. Isn't it just zero at some point in $D$?

Comment: If $v$ is not identically zero, then its zeroes $Z$ have to be isolated. So, exclude them, and apply your CR argument to $D\setminus Z$. So your function is constant on $D\setminus Z$, and by identity principle it's constant on the whole $D$

Comment: @Joe: The zeros of a harmonic function are not isolated.

Comment: If they are not isolated, say $v=0$ on $U\subset D$, then apply the OP argument on $D\setminus U$ and my argument on $U$.

Comment: How do you know that $D\setminus Z$ has an accumulation point (in order to apply identity principle)?

Comment: @durianice: if $D$ is open and $Z$ is discrete, then $D\setminus Z$ has accumulation points.